# Insert code in Stack Overflow mobile site

Tags: bug, mobile-web

I'm currently accessing Stack Overflow through the mobile site (on a phone), and I tried without joy to insert a code block (seemingly, I'm not the only one who has had this problem).

I tried to put four spaces before and after the code.  This is not working.

Please be more clear in your explanation or add simple `[code]` or `[quote]` markup that would be more logical.

Comment: 4 spaces before each line **and** a line break before thw ehole block should be used. there's no need to suffice 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what if my code is 40 lignes long?

Comment: Good luck tapping 161 times (alternatively, you could just post your unformatted code, with a note in which you mention that you're using a mobile device which is uncapable of indenting code. Most users (well, at least me) would edit your post and format it for you).

Comment: A bug? Seriously?

Comment: You are good in mathematic and a nice person... Unfortunately, stackover do not let me post a ppost with a code if it hasn t been quote properly...

Comment: @user1486850 Slide to the bottom of the page, then tap "Full site". You should see the full Markdown editor, which can be used to indent code. A last resort, which should actually not be used, is to paste code at an external (but reliable!) host, such as http://pastebin.com/. 40 lines of code is quite much, by the way. Are you sure that it cannot be stripped down to, say, 5 lines?

Comment: I can understand posting code in an _answer_ from mobile (I do it all the time, it's quite difficult) but I don't understand why you'd post a question? If you've got 40 lines of code you've a problem with, surely better to post the question from your coding machine? You're not going to manually type 40 lines without introducing errors in your question.

Comment: A lot has happened since 2012, and it ought to be indicated somehow. E.g., what are some cross references? A starter: *[Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/)* - *"On 2022-03-02 we removed the Mobile button from the footer. This means the mobile views are removed entirely from Stack Overflow."*

Comment: Mobile web is gone now, this question is non relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/282094) and    https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/282094

Answer (score 3):

One easy way to insert a code block is to highlight your code and click the curly braces button in the editing bar (the ones that look like "{ }"). This should automatically format your code into a codeblock.

Comment: Tempted to upvote, but... 404

Comment: Yeah, @Yawus what were you thinking!?!?

Comment: @DanielFischer Whew. Dodged a bullet there.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Well, that's why I want that reputation lock! That way, I can satisfy my addiction to Q&A without possibly increasing my reputation!

Comment: Well I m connecting with a phone so there is no bracket on it. And well I use the "full website" it doesn t work with the phone (I tried...) but thanks! – Giom 19 mins ago !

Comment: Ah. Your message wasn't exactly clear about you being on the mobile site. In that case, you should probably follow Rob W's suggestion.

Comment: @Giom on your phone you can still enter 4 spaces and a carriage return, or surround the code with `backticks` - `

Comment: Or, you know, don't try to enter code on the mobile site.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill yes, that is probably true too.

Comment: True wasn't clear i apologize. So you suggest me to use the fulll site?

Comment: @user1486850 If you want to post code blocks (I'd say 10+ lines), then yes. If you can get by with in-line code (surround with backticks `), then you should be fine. Although, I'm not sure if you can access a backtick from a phone.

Comment: @Yawus you can on an iPhone and iPad, but it's a cumbersome PITA, made even more so by AutoMangle.

Comment: This person needs 20 downvotes to get back to 404. Let's get started before it's too late!

Comment: (That real downvote is not mine, though...)

Comment: He he, what that a 404 error? Guys you are making jokes but it is a matter of life or death don't you see?  Have a good day! Haha

Answer (score 2):

Well apparently I need to put spaces (before all the lines...) because the ``` doesn't works for more than a single Line with iPhone. It is very complicate with a mobile...

Comment: Note: code fences now work, though on mobile I prefer three tildes instead of backticks (`~~~`). The other answer will work too since mobile now uses the same pages as desktop.